# JQGrid Form Editing Label/Column width

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid and use form editing on this grid.  The issue I am having is that the columns that I have marked as editable are not the correct width.  I haven't been able to find the appropriate option in the API, either in the colModel or in the form options.  For example, I have a text field that should be ~35 characters wide, but it is only displaying as ~15.  Let me know if a code example is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be several way to solve this. You will try with the following way :

1. In colModel you can use **`editoptions: {size:50}`**
2. If it doesn't work then you can use the following :

   editoptions: { 
       dataInit: function(elem) {
           $(elem).width(50);  // set the width which you need
       }
   }

or you can write the following css which helps you change all the elements at a time

```
table.EditTable > tbody > tr.FormData > td.DataTD > input[type="text"] {
    width: 115px !important;
}

table.EditTable > tbody > tr.FormData > td.DataTD > select, 
table.EditTable > tbody > tr.FormData > td.DataTD > input, 
table.EditTable > tbody > tr.FormData > td.DataTD > textarea {
    width: 115px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [size](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#text) property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions). For example `editoptions:{size:35}`. Probably you will have to use additionally [width](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) property of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) in the `prmEdit` parameter of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition).

Comment: @Joseph: You are welcome! Not a problem with accepting. You made all correct. The most important is that the problem is solved.